# Scrollspy not working

Tags: scroll, spy

i got this code, and no matter what i do, the scroll spy won't work, can anyone shed some light into it? thanks in advance!

```
<div class='corpo effect8'>
        <div class='esquerda'>
            <div id="como-nav" class='como-menu'>
                <div class="como-menu-topo">menu</div>
                <ul class="como-menu-links">
                    <li class><a href="#intro">introdução</a></li><div class="divisor-como"></div>
                    <li class><a href="#quemsomos">quem somos</a></li><div class="divisor-como"></div>
                    <li class><a href="#queremos">o que queremos</a></li><div class="divisor-como"></div>
                    <li class><a href="#coletadedados">coleta de dados</a></li><div class="divisor-como"></div>
                    <li class><a href="#ferramentas">ferramentas</a></li><div class="divisor-como"></div>
                    <li class><a href="#faq">FAQ</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="como-texto" class="comofunciona" data-spy="scroll" data-target="#como-nav" data-offset="0">
            <h3 id="intro">introdução</h3>
            <p>Ad leggings keytar, brunch id art party dolor labore. Pitchfork yr enim lo-fi before they sold out qui. Tumblr farm-to-table bicycle rights whatever. Anim keffiyeh carles cardigan. Velit seitan mcsweeney's photo booth 3 wolf moon irure. Cosby sweater lomo jean shorts, williamsburg hoodie minim qui you probably haven't heard of them et cardigan trust fund culpa biodiesel wes anderson aesthetic. Nihil tattooed accusamus, cred irony biodiesel keffiyeh artisan ullamco consequat.</p>
            <h3 id="quemsomos">quem somos</h3>
            <p>Ad leggings keytar, brunch id art party dolor labore. Pitchfork yr enim lo-fi before they sold out qui. Tumblr farm-to-table bicycle rights whatever. Anim keffiyeh carles cardigan. Velit seitan mcsweeney's photo booth 3 wolf moon irure. Cosby sweater lomo jean shorts, williamsburg hoodie minim qui you probably haven't heard of them et cardigan trust fund culpa biodiesel wes anderson aesthetic. Nihil tattooed accusamus, cred irony biodiesel keffiyeh artisan ullamco consequat.</p>
            <h3 id="queremos">o que queremos</h3>
            <p>Ad leggings keytar, brunch id art party dolor labore. Pitchfork yr enim lo-fi before they sold out qui. Tumblr farm-to-table bicycle rights whatever. Anim keffiyeh carles cardigan. Velit seitan mcsweeney's photo booth 3 wolf moon irure. Cosby sweater lomo jean shorts, williamsburg hoodie minim qui you probably haven't heard of them et cardigan trust fund culpa biodiesel wes anderson aesthetic. Nihil tattooed accusamus, cred irony biodiesel keffiyeh artisan ullamco consequat.</p>
            <h3 id="coletadedados">coleta de dados</h3>
            <p>Ad leggings keytar, brunch id art party dolor labore. Pitchfork yr enim lo-fi before they sold out qui. Tumblr farm-to-table bicycle rights whatever. Anim keffiyeh carles cardigan. Velit seitan mcsweeney's photo booth 3 wolf moon irure. Cosby sweater lomo jean shorts, williamsburg hoodie minim qui you probably haven't heard of them et cardigan trust fund culpa biodiesel wes anderson aesthetic. Nihil tattooed accusamus, cred irony biodiesel keffiyeh artisan ullamco consequat.</p>
            <h3 id="ferramentas">ferramentas</h3>
            <p>Ad leggings keytar, brunch id art party dolor labore. Pitchfork yr enim lo-fi before they sold out qui. Tumblr farm-to-table bicycle rights whatever. Anim keffiyeh carles cardigan. Velit seitan mcsweeney's photo booth 3 wolf moon irure. Cosby sweater lomo jean shorts, williamsburg hoodie minim qui you probably haven't heard of them et cardigan trust fund culpa biodiesel wes anderson aesthetic. Nihil tattooed accusamus, cred irony biodiesel keffiyeh artisan ullamco consequat.</p>
            <h3 id="faq">faq</h3>
            <p>Ad leggings keytar, brunch id art party dolor labore. Pitchfork yr enim lo-fi before they sold out qui. Tumblr farm-to-table bicycle rights whatever. Anim keffiyeh carles cardigan. Velit seitan mcsweeney's photo booth 3 wolf moon irure. Cosby sweater lomo jean shorts, williamsburg hoodie minim qui you probably haven't heard of them et cardigan trust fund culpa biodiesel wes anderson aesthetic. Nihil tattooed accusamus, cred irony biodiesel keffiyeh artisan ullamco consequat.</p>

        </div>
```

Comment: Mostly a javascript error, we can't help you without giving us the js code

Comment: i dont have a js code, i read somewhere that i didn't need one if i called it in the html code... im sorry if this sound stupid, but this is my first time doing a website...

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be tough to troubleshoot because you've only provided the markup for a div. Consider linking to a jsfiddle so we can get the complete picture.

When I was having issues with scrollspy it was because I had placed the js code up in the head instead of at the bottom of the body. Try placing

```
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

(or whatever version of BS you are using) just before closing the body tag.